# Alignment in a navigation bar - very beginner

Tags: html, css

friends. I am a very beginner of HTML and CSS

I am a bit confused as to how I can center the text(CUSTOMER, FAQ, and CONTACT) on the navigation bar.

I have tried vertically center-aligned but it still continues to stick to the top. Thank you very much for your help.

```css
nav {
  background-color: RGB(80, 80, 95);
  height: 50px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

nav a {
  float: inline;
  width: 200px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.pull-right{
  text-aling: center;
}

body{
  background-color:black;
  font-family:Lobster;
  color:white;
}

h1{
  padding:0;
  margin-top:0px;
  font-size:5.0em;
  padding-top:0%;
}

.btn-default{
  background-color:black;
  border-color:black;
  color:#337ab7;
  font-size:1.7em;
  margin-top:1%;
}

.pageOne{
  background:url("http://www.chairmanenglish.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/img_title_bg.jpg");
 background-size:cover;
  padding-bottom:10%;
  padding-top:10%;
  margin-top:80px;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<header>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
</header>

<div class="pageOne text-center" id="p1">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills navbar-fixed-top">
    <li class="logo-left-top">
      <a href="#p1"><img src="http://www.chairmanenglish.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/img_bi_top.png" width="100px" heigth="50px"></a>
    </li>
      
    <li class="pull-right">
      <a href="#p4">CONTACT</a>
    </li>
    <li class="pull-right">
      <a href="#p2">FAQ</a>
    </li>

     <li class="pull-right">
      <a href="#p3">CUSTOMER</a>
    </li>
          
  </ul>
```

Comment: You’re using `nav` in your CSS but you have `nav` classes, not elements. They should both be `.nav` instead.

Comment: You have a typo in `pull-right` as well

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with:

```
.pull-right{
    width: 25%;
}
```

Along with a correction to some of your errors that others mentioned.

Please take a look here: http://codepen.io/Squeakasaur/pen/vxrgYd